# CrystalReportViewer Shows blank Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am creating a webpage where I want a crystal viewer, I have rpt file and in my webpage code I have written inside page load event

```
 report = new ReportDocument();
        //report.FileName = Server.MapPath(@"reports\Ledger.rpt");
        report.Load(Server.MapPath(@"reports\Ledger.rpt"));
        string server = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];
        string user = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportUserID"];
        string password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportUserPwd"];
        string database = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDatabase"];
        report.SetDatabaseLogon(user, password, server, database);
        string strSelection = "1=1 ";
        string strTitle = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyName"].ToString();
        string strTitle1 = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"].ToString();
        report.SetParameterValue("CompanyName", strTitle);
        report.SetParameterValue("AppName", strTitle1);
        report.SetParameterValue("startDate", DateTime.Now);
        report.SetParameterValue("endDate", DateTime.Now);


        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

and In my aspx file I have

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
            AutoDataBind="true"   
            ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
            <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server" >
                                <Report FileName="reports\Ledger.rpt">
                                </Report>
                            </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

whatever I do It shows blank report only, what should I do for this??
Please help

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Report Viewer you have Visible = "false", can you change it to true?

Comment: It does't help I posted visible="false" mistakenly